# iText 5 Add a text field under a paragraph

Tags: itext, textfield

I'm using iText to create a PDF in my java spring mvc web project. I'm new to iText 5. Could anyone tell me how to add a text field under a paragraph? Based on my current code, the text field is not displayed under the paragraph. I may add more questions to the PDF so I want to display each text field under the paragraph.

```
try {
    List<FormQuestionBean> questions = formBuilderBean.getQuestions();
    MyHeaderAndFooter event = new MyHeaderAndFooter();
    Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    pdfDocument.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 30);
    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, pdfBaos);
    writer.setPageEvent(event);
    pdfDocument.open();
    Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(FORM_NAME + " : " + formBuilderBean.getName(), HEADING);
    paragraph1.setSpacingAfter(20);
    pdfDocument.add(paragraph1);

    for (FormQuestionBean formQuestionBean: questions) {
        if (formQuestionBean.getFieldImplementation().contentEquals("Text Field")) {
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(formQuestionBean.getName());
            pdfDocument.add(p);
            TextField text = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(36, 788, 559, 806), "text" );             
            text.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
            PdfFormField field = text.getTextField();
            writer.addAnnotation(field);
        }

    }

    pdfDocument.close();
    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(pdfBaos.size()));
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(pdfBaos.size());
    String downloadName = getFormFileName(".pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadName + "\"");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    pdfBaos.writeTo(outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `PdfWriter` has a method `getVerticalPosition` to determine *the current vertical page position*. You might use this. Alternatively you can use a `Chunk` with a generic tag. Or you can use tables with custom cell events.

Comment: I'll give a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: *Update: I figured out using table and cell* - if you consider that a solution of your issue, please make it an answer to your question instead of editing it into the question. If you don't consider it a solution for you, please make that clear and point out, which aspects you dislike.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out using table and cell. Below is the code:

```
try {
        List<FormQuestionBean> questions = formBuilderBean.getQuestions();
        MyHeaderAndFooter event = new MyHeaderAndFooter();
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        pdfDocument.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 30);
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, pdfBaos);
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        pdfDocument.open();
        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(FORM_NAME + " : " + formBuilderBean.getName(), HEADING);
        paragraph1.setSpacingAfter(20);
        pdfDocument.add(paragraph1);

        for (FormQuestionBean formQuestionBean: questions) {
            if (formQuestionBean.getFieldImplementation().contentEquals("Text Field")) {
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(formQuestionBean.getName()));
                c1.setFixedHeight(30);
                table.addCell(c1);
                PdfPCell c2 = new PdfPCell();
                TextField text = new TextField(writer, c2, "text" );               
                text.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
                FieldPositioningEvents events = new FieldPositioningEvents(writer, text.getTextField()); 
                c2.setCellEvent(events);
                c2.setFixedHeight(30);
                table.addCell(c2);
                pdfDocument.add(table);

            }
        }
        pdfDocument.close();
        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(pdfBaos.size()));
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(pdfBaos.size());
        String downloadName = getFormFileName(".pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadName + "\"");
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        pdfBaos.writeTo(outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```